# Building a search layer index on avro serialized data

Tags: hadoop, serialization, solr, avro

I have my avro serialized data on hdfs. Now I'm trying to build a search interface where I can query the avro data and fetch the results. I can use the following approach, but it has some disvantages:

Deserialize the avro data and add it in hive store and build a indexing layer using some solr/lucene and run the queries.
What if the avro schema has multiple layers, like

```
   {
        name: "xyz",
        height: "180cm",
        Cities_residing: ["X", "Y", "Z"]
        Hotels_checkedin : ["X", "Y", "Z"],
        itemX : {
            itemY : {
                itemZ : "546"
                    }
                }
    }
```

Now, storing the above hierarchial data record will be difficult. Also, I don't want to replicate the data like deserializing the avro records and storing in some document store. It introduces lot of replication.
So, im looking for a serach tool over avro serialized data(having multiple hierarchies).
In case if existing tools are already solving this problem. Please point me to those.

Comment: Interested what solution you arrived at as looking to query azure eventhub records captured in .avro files?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in Java, [SortedKeyValueFile](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/53a7d9feef4b857be7dbe6aa5b2744b086384302/lang/java/mapred/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/hadoop/file/SortedKeyValueFile.java) may be an alternative worth exploring.  At this time, I am not aware of a similar implementation in python or C/C++.  This is obviously not as generic as `BigQuery`; however, it may solve use cases where you only need to query by key within a file.

Answer (score 0):

The big cloud providers now have solutions for searching through avro files. 
[AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/02/amazon-athena-supports-querying-avro-data-is-available-in-the-us-east-ohio-region-and-integrates-with-looker/) and [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro) are two examples of services that might solve your issue. Especially if you are willing to switch from hdfs to S3 or similar service.